# How to get a range of objects in a selector

Tags: jquery

If I have a list of 10 links, and I want to select all the links after the first 4, How?

I was looking at [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) but that doesn't seem to solve my issue since its specific, rather than a range.

Look for something like `$("a:eq(>4)")` or something, hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:gt` selector:

```
$('a:gt(3)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice`. It's [faster](http://jsperf.com/select-all-but-first-42).

```
$('a').slice(4);
```